# I can't play media file with setDataSource

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I got a path of media file and want to play it.The problem is MediaPlayer.create() work successfully but  when I use setDataSource,it's not working correctly, the media not play the music

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
 String path = 
"/storage/emulated/0/Music/AThousandYears_ChristinaPerri.mp3";
            try {
                player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), 
                Uri.parse(path));
                player.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I did not got any exception. Sorry about my bad english.I hope someone help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try{
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songPath);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
   }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle Exception
    }
```